# How to prevent html link underline in when sent from outlook to gmail?

Tags: html, hyperlink, outlook, gmail, html-email

I try to copy-paste rendered html that includes anchor tag to outlook, for example:

```
<a href="tel:1000000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: #4e4b4c;">1000000000</a>
```

(I select the rendered html with right click -> select all)

but when I send the mail to gmail I receive the links with underline. I tried to give this element `text-decoration: none;` style but it doesn't work.

Here is a code example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdKrvj

On outlook (sending side):

[image: outlook after copy-paste]

On gmail (receiving side):

[image: gmail after receiving]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The links are placed because Gmail places a list style around your link example:

```
.ii a[href] { color: #15c; }
```

A way around this is add a span around your phone number (or address)

```
<span class="contact">675 Massachusetts Ave.<br>Cambridge, MA 02139, USA</span>
```

Then using CSS you can target that specific element and set it's style

```
.contact a {color:#000000!important; text-decoration:underline!important;}
```

Full article (with second option) can be found [here.](https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-fix-blue-links-in-gmail)

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: The OP is sending from MS Outlook, so those added classes are removed. Overriding  `.ii a[href] { text-decoration:none; }` would affect the whole email. In order to style only the desired links I'm trying set these styles with no luck so far:  `.ii a[href] span { text-decoration:none; }`, `.ii td a[href] { text-decoration:none; }`. Setting `display: inline-block` to the span element to not inherit the parent `text-decoration` style doesn't work either since MS Outlook also removes `inline-block` when processing the email.

Comment: The post was edited it seems. If i had known this was sent thru Outlook, i would simply said not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've found inlining a `text-decoration: none;` isn't enough. Annoying, right? I've added the following code to bulletproof auto-detected links like this. Basically add a class to any parent element (like a `<td>` or `<div>`) that *might* contain a phone number or mailing address that an email client might detect.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    *[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors,    /* Gmail */
    .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
    .aBn {
        border-bottom: 0 !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="x-gmail-data-detectors">
    <a href="tel:1000000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: #4e4b4c;">1000000000</a>
</td>
```

I've seen this generally work, though depending on which flavor of Gmail you're testing, results might vary.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work since MS Outlook strips out the `text-decoration` inline style so Gmail is receiving the `<a>` element unstyled and is applying their own styles: `.ii a[href] {text-decoration: underline}`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a weird quirk, but here's the code that should work:

```html
<a href="tel:666" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <span class="txt" style="text-decoration:none; color:pink;">Call ME</span>
</a>
```

So, let me explain a little. Outlook, is a funny beast. It tends to ignore some styling on anchor tags and overwrites it with its own styles, but only sometimes, and only for some css.

**Here's what I did and why it works:**

Anchor Tag:

- on the anchor tag and I set `text-decoration:none;` in its style attribute. This is to prevent the anchor tag from adding an underline in default link color to the content.

Span/Inline Element within Anchor Tag:

- I use an inline element to hold and style the text within the anchor tag (benefits of being more specific to avoid the style overwrites). In this case, I'm using a span element. I also do not use a block level element because most email clients do not use HTML5 and before HTML5 it is specified that anchor tags can only contain inline elements. Trying to put tables or block elements inside can break things or have unexpected results.
- I added a `class="txt"` attribute to the `<span>` in order to help prevent outlook from overwriting our styles. The `txt` class doesn't actually need to exist or be styled, it just needs to have a working class on it. The one exception I've found to this is that you don't need a class attribute on the `<strong>` element
- Next I added a style attribute in which I once again put `text-decoration:none;` and I put the `color` styling here as well. The reason I do this is to prevent outlook from overwriting on links that have been clicked before, and also to prevent outlook from overwriting the color of the link text as it does in some versions.

This should work across outlook and gmail and is what I've been using when coding HTML emails.